# jQuery Mobile: Can I "uninitialize" the page?

Tags: jquery, testing, jquery-mobile

Is there a way to "uninitialize" a page that has been initialized by jQuery Mobile?  I am running an entire test suite on a single page and would like to cleanup JQM after each test.  It's currently setup like this:

```
before(function () {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
    $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;
    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'slide';

    this.$el = $('<div></div>');
    $(document.body).append(this.$el);
});

after(function () {
    this.$el.remove();
});

afterEach(function () {
    this.$el.empty();
});

it('some test', function () {
    var page = $('<div data-role="page">...</div>')
    this.$el.append(page);

    // Each test will perform calls like these at some point
    $.mobile.initializePage();
    $.mobile.changePage(page, {
        allowSamePageTransition: true,
        pageContainer: this.$el,
        transition: 'none'
    });

    assert_whatever();
});
```

The first test runs fine but when the second one runs I get the error:

```
cannot call methods on loader prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'show'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like setting:

```
$.mobile.activePage = undefined;
$.mobile.loaderWidget = undefined;
```

Before each test does the trick.

Comment: Thank you, you must have saved me days of painful agony.